# Insert into database texfield, seperate values in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp, struts2, jquery-tageditor

I am implementing `Tag System` with `Struts`. I have two tables in database,`Blog` and `Tag` using `Hibernate` with many to many relationship. I have integrated [JQuery tagEditor](http://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html). When I insert a single value it's ok, but when I insert more than one values(Tags),it is inserting like a single value in database.
[image: Tag table]

I haven't experience in javascript. How to separate values in textfield and send this values to server side to insert in database?

**`create.jsp`:**

```
    <s:form action="execCreate">
        <div class="form-group">
            <s:label for="title" key="global.title" />
            <s:textfield cssClass="form-control" key="blog.title" 
                name="blog.title" id="title" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <s:textarea  id="wysihtml5-editor" cssStyle="height:400px" name="blog.description"
                key="blog.description" placeholder="Enter Description..."/>
        </div>
        
    <div class="taginput">
            <s:label for="tag" value="Tag"/>
            <s:textfield cssClass="form-control" key="tag.name" cssStyle="height:50px;"
                name="tag.name" id="tag" />
        </div>  
        
    <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-primary" key="global.submit"/>
</s:form>


<script>
 $('#tag').tagEditor({ 
    autocomplete: {
        
        delay: 0, // show suggestions immediately
        clickDelete:true,
        position: { collision: 'flip' }, // automatic menu position up/down
        placeholder: 'Enter tags ...',
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'blog/listTag.html',
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(jsonResponse) {
                    response(jsonResponse.tagList);
                    
                }
            });
            },

    },

    }); 

</script>
```

**`BlogAction.java`:**

```
public String execCreate() {


         try {
        facade.createBlog(blog,tag);
        return "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(
                Logger.EVENT_FAILURE,
                "could not insert blog values, error: *"
                        + e.getMessage() + "*");
    }

    return "input";

}
```

**`BlogService.java`:**

```
   @Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public void createBlog(Blog blog,Tag tags) {

 
            Blog newBlog = new Blog();

    User user = (User) ESAPI.authenticator().getCurrentUser();
    
    Tag tag=new Tag();
    String name[]=tags.getName();
for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
    tag.setName(tags.getName());
    tag.setDate(new Date());
    em.persist(tag);
    em.flush();
}

    try {
        Set<Tag> listTag = blog.getTag();
        listTag.add(tag);

        newBlog.setTag(listTag);
        newBlog.setTitle(blog.getTitle());
        newBlog.setDescription(blog.getDescription());
        newBlog.setCreated(new Date());
        newBlog.setUser(user);
        em.merge(newBlog);
        em.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info(Logger.SECURITY_SUCCESS, "blog created successfully");


}
```

**I edited my question and BLOB values appear in my database**.

Comment: Do you have a specific question, what errors do you have?

Comment: Modify how values are sent to action or parse them in action.

Comment: @RomanC ,I'm in this situation:I have a many to many relationship between blog and tags tables.When i insert blog attribute(title,description,tags),i want to send seperate tag values to server,because one blog may have many tags.I think i sholud sperate with javscript from client side and send those seperate values to server but ai am not clearly.My "error" is that when tags is inserting in database it is insrting as a string,not seperate values.

Comment: @AleksandrM ,can you help me with code?

Comment: With code to do what? Split the string?

Comment: @AleksandrM ,i have done  my problem before like you say me now and it works.I will update my question with my solution.Thanks for your comment,you helped with your first comment.I split the string and i create new Tag object for every string cames from input.But on Tag table may have duplicate name of tags and when try to find blog with tag(for example:list blog for a single tag,for java maybe) i am not clearly.Is this a problem?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.I split name(Tag name,type of String) and i create new Tag object for every string comes.I change only BlogService.java.

BlogService.java(updated)

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public void createBlog(Blog blog, Tag tags) {

    logger.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "Trying to add a throwException: "
            + throwException);

    Blog newBlog = new Blog();


    Set<Tag> listTag = blog.getTag();

    String name = tags.getName();
    ArrayList aList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(name.split(",")));

    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setName((String) aList.get(i));
        tag.setDate(new Date());
        listTag.add(tag);
        em.persist(tag);
        em.flush();

    }

    try {

        newBlog.setTag(listTag);
        newBlog.setTitle(blog.getTitle());
        newBlog.setDescription(blog.getDescription());
        newBlog.setCreated(new Date());
        newBlog.setUser(user);

        Set<Blog> listBlog = tags.getBlog();
        listBlog.add(newBlog);

        em.persist(newBlog);
        em.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info(Logger.SECURITY_SUCCESS,
            "Blog updated successfully");

}
```

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

Struts supports a conversion of comma separated values to array or `List`. You need to change your property type to one of these types. For example a `Tag` would have a property

```
private String[] name;
//getters and setters
```

Once you got an array in `name` property you should change the code  accordingly.

Comment: I changed type of name and it display Blob value in database that i can not understand.for example:I insert(java,struts,hiberante) tag name and in database it is inserting BLOB value,can you help me when you say:"you should change the code accordingly.".What change should i do in the code.Thank you!

Comment: It should be string type and because you know how to save a single value yo can proceed with the array iteration, this part of code should be processed accordingly.

Comment: Yes,i have string type like you told me.Do you mean i should iterate this array in BlogService.java and persist those value?Why BLOB it is display in database as a name value,instead of tags name?Thank you and sorry for my duplicate question.

Comment: It shouldn't be BLOB, but VARCHAR2

Comment: I edit my question.I changed database photo and BlogService.java and it BLOB value apear in my database.Can you edit my question?Thank you!